# fastapi adding eureka is throwing RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running

Tags: python, fastapi, netflix-eureka

My project have the following structure:

[image]

I want to add eureka to my fastapi applicaction, I´'m trying to do that in the **init**.py file:

```
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()

eureka_client.init(eureka_server="http://eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/",
                   app_name="your_app_name",
                   instance_port=8000)
```

Also I'm using uvicorn to run the app like this:

```
uvicorn landus.main:app --reload
```

But I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

I saw a few links like this https://github.com/keijack/python-eureka-client/issues/76 but I don't understand how it works, I only know that fastapi or uvicorn are async application and when I add eureka, that is another async application is where a get this error, but don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I make it work executing the init_async function and using asynccontextmanager form fast api:

```
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as eureka_client
from fastapi import FastAPI
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from landus.controladores import controladorRouter


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    await eureka_client.init_async(
        eureka_server="http://eureka-primary:8011/eureka/,http://eureka-secondary:8012/eureka/,http://eureka-tertiary:8013/eureka/",
        app_name="msprueba",
        instance_port=8000,
        instance_host="localhost"
    )
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
app.include_router(controladorRouter)
```

The problem was that I cannot execute a code that is also async with fastapi, so the lifespan function execute before fastapi run